# Using Composer to install npm and bower packages on production (i.e. no devDependencies)

Tags: php, laravel, npm, composer-php, bower

In my composer.json file I have the following in the scripts section:

```
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize",
        "npm install",
        "bower install"
    ]
```

When running 'composer install' this will cause npm and bower to install all their dependencies, which by default include devDependencies. When it comes to doing a production rollout (e.g. 'composer install --no-dev' I want to fire up 'npm install --production' and 'bower install --production')

As far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a way to either change the list specified for 'post-install-command' depending on flags passed, or a way of setting variables that can then be passed to commands in post-install-cmd.

Am I missing something? It doesn't seem possible to use composer to do both a dev and production install using just the config. Do I really have to use `composer install --no-scripts` on production and then manually run all four of the commands myself? That seems a little clunky.

Comment: Composer is a _dependency manager_, __not__ a _build/deployment tool_. So maybe you should be looking for something like [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com), [Ant](http://ant.apache.org), [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com), [Phing](http://www.phing.info), etc.

Answer (score 19):

You could always make use of PHP to do environment detection for you, then install other dependencies from the same script. This isn't nice and clean, like including npm and bower in post-install-cmd, but it will get you what you're looking for.

```
"post-install-cmd": [
     "php artisan clear-compiled",
     "php artisan optimize",
     "php path/to/installer.php"
 ]
```

Example installer.php:

```
// Logic to determine the environment. This could be determined many ways, and depends on how your
// application's environment is determined. If you're making use of Laravel's environment
// capabilities, you could do the following:
$env = trim(exec('php artisan env'));

// Clean up response to get the value we actually want
$env = substr($env, strrpos($env, ' ') + 1);

$envFlag = ($env === 'production')
    ? '--production'
    : '';

// Install npm
passthru("npm install {$envFlag}");
// Install bower
passthru("bower install {$envFlag}");
```

You could make this example more robust, and even create an Artisan command for it.

Comment: Your post install/update script would fail coz you are assuming that npm is installed on the user's machine, which may unlikely be the case.

Comment: I think it's a fair assumption that npm is installed, as the OP provided those commands originally.

Comment: Sorry the comment was meant for the OP, and I don't intend to down play your answer. Just a note sorta thing. It may work fine for the OP. But if the package being developed is intended for the community at large it will fail unless explicitly specified in the installation docs.

Comment: No worries :). From the OP's question, I believe he's not looking to have this setup for a public package, but instead, for his, or his team's, dev workflow. It sounds like he'd want the development-related packages installed for each developer, then deploy his site/app, and have that deployment use the --production flags when installing on the production server(s).

Answer (score 5):

This would work;

```
"post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize",
        "npm install",
        "bower install"
    ],
"post-install-cmd": [
    "php artisan clear-compiled",
    "php artisan optimize",
    "npm install --production",
    "bower install --production"
]
```

i.e. you should be running 'update' on your dev environment, and only ever run 'install' on your production environment.

Comment: That would work fine if I was in a team of one, but if I want other team members to pick up the current version of all the packages in composer from the .lock file, they wouldn't be able to. They'd be forced to either update all the packages or miss out the dev dependencies.

Comment: Then I assume you should run 'composer install' first and the 'composer update'. Should not be an issue for developer.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of hack but you can get the parent command's PID with `$PPID` in bash. From that you can get the commandline arguments.

```
"post-install-cmd": [
    "ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | grep no-dev > /dev/null && echo called with no-dev || echo called without no-dev",
],
```

If you were to do this, I'd put it in a bash script and run it like this: `run-if-env-is-production.sh "bower install --production"`

I would recommend @kwoodfriend's solution over this though, as this is less portable as it requires bash, ps & grep.

Answer (score 1):

Because I use npm, bower and gulp to build my assets, I don't need any of them on production, so here is the composer.json I use:

```
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize",
        "(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | grep -q no-dev && true) || npm --loglevel silent install",
        "(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | grep -q no-dev && true) || npm --loglevel silent install --global bower",
        "(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | grep -q no-dev && true) || bower --silent install"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize",
        "(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | grep -q no-dev && true) || npm --loglevel silent update",
        "(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | grep -q no-dev && true) || bower --silent update"
    ]
```

... But it looks strange to me to use such a tricky command in order to detect dev environment, or not...