# composer package requiring npm dependencies

Tags: npm, package.json, composer-php

I'm creating a small Laravel package, I've set it up in `package/my-package` and initiated a `composer.json` in `package/my-package/composer.json`.

It's working fine, but I need to add dependencies like `Bootstrap`, `jQuery`, `jQuery Datatables`...
How should I use npm to install thoses dependencies automatically after composer is done installing?

Like for example, after publishing the package, users should only use `composer require my-packakge/my-package` and it should install everything including the dependencies I mentioned.

I've tried adding this code to my `composer.json`, but it did nothing:

```
"extra": {
     "npm": {
          "bootstrap": "^4.3.1"
     },
}
```

Should I add a separate `package.json` file in addition to `composer.json` ? if so how will it work ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Composer to install npm and bower packages on production (i.e. no devDependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122187/using-composer-to-install-npm-and-bower-packages-on-production-i-e-no-devdepen)

Comment: @NicoHaase It doesn't, I was looking for a better way like the `extra` key added to `composer.json` like I mentioned in my question.

Comment: And what makes you think that something like that is possible? Composer does not have any support for NPM